# Is it possible to sync two TFS(TFVS) repositories?

Tags: tfs, synchronization, azure-devops, tfvc

I have 2 different TFS repositories (one is TFS 2012, another is TFS 2017).

What I need is:

1) Work in single workspace on my local machine, change code, do changesets...

2) All the changes should go to both repositories (they should be identical, but located in different places)

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible; what you're describing is not a common or supported scenario.

Comment: @Vladimir Melekh Based on your 2 requirements mentioned above, it's not possible. I can think of is that with respective workspace for both TFS, copy changes from one to another, add to source control, then check in. But I think it's not worth trying.